# SQL Comparison Operator Issue) ...right syntax to use near '>'2021-06-01' AND 100*(d1_close-close)/close>'29'' at line 1")

Tags: python, sql, escaping

I'm trying to run a SQL query through python file, and I'm getting the error message

```
... right syntax to use near '>'2021-06-01' AND 100*(d1_close-close)/close>'29'' at line 1")
```

My query code is as below:

```
sql = "WITH comparing_price AS (SELECT CODE, DATE, OPEN, high, low, close, volume,"\
                "LEAD(OPEN, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_open',"\
                "LEAD(OPEN, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_open',"\
                "LEAD(OPEN, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_open',"\
                "LEAD(high, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_high',"\
                "LEAD(high, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_high',"\
                "LEAD(high, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_high',"\
                "LEAD(high, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd4_high',"\
                "LEAD(low, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_low',"\
                "LEAD(low, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_low',"\
                "LEAD(low, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_low',"\
                "LEAD(close, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_close',"\
                "LEAD(close, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_close',"\
                "LEAD(close, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_close',"\
                "LEAD(volume, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_volume',"\
                "LEAD(volume, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_volume',"\
                "AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA5',"\
                "AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 7 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA10',"\
                "AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 17 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA20',"\
                "AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 57 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA60',"\
                "AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 117 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA120',"\
                "STD(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 17 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_std'"\
            "FROM daily_price)"\
        "SELECT * "\
        "FROM comparing_price"\
        "WHERE DATE>\'2021-06-01\' AND 100*(d1_close-close)/close>\'29\'"
        curs.execute(sql)
```

I have also tried different versions like below:

```
conditions=('2021-06-01','29')
...
....
"WHERE DATE>%s AND 100*(d1_close-close)/close>%s"
curs.execute(sql, conditions)
```

UPDATE)) I think the syntax error is in the comparison operator. How can I send comparison operator from python to SQL?

Comment: You can use 3 double quotes to enclose your SQL query, like """SQL QUERY""". Try this and your issue should be solved. :)

Comment: I've also tried tripple quotes, it still does not work...

Comment: Can you move the condition after "AND" to a new line, need to check which line is at fault? did you try to convert '2021-06-01' to type DATE? conditions like > = < etc are implemented on numeric types, please move 29 out of single quotes. SHARE error message once done.

Comment: I've figured out that I had a space missing in between FROM and WHERE statements! Tripple quotes helped me afterwards. Thank you!

Comment: awesome :). Happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triple quotes allow you to write the query without string concatenation because the strings can span multiple lines:

```
sql = """WITH comparing_price AS (SELECT CODE, DATE, OPEN, high, low, close, volume,
                LEAD(OPEN, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_open',
                LEAD(OPEN, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_open',
                LEAD(OPEN, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_open',
                "LEAD(high, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_high',
                LEAD(high, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_high',
                LEAD(high, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_high',
                LEAD(high, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd4_high',
                LEAD(low, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_low',
                LEAD(low, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_low',
                LEAD(low, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_low',
                LEAD(close, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_close',
                LEAD(close, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_close',"\
                LEAD(close, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_close',
                LEAD(volume, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_volume',
                LEAD(volume, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_volume',
                AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA5',
                AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 7 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA10',
                AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 17 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA20',
                AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 57 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA60',
                AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 117 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA120',
                STD(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 17 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_std'
            FROM daily_price)
        SELECT * 
        FROM comparing_price
        WHERE DATE > '2021-06-01' AND 100*(d1_close-close)/close"""
```

This also makes it easier to test because you can just copy the query to another tool to run it.